# Dominated convergence application?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm reviewing for an exam and trying to solve Rudin 11.16, which I think (not sure though) is an application of the dominated convergence theorem:

Suppose $\{n_k\}$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers and $E$ is the set of all $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$ at which $\sin n_k x$ converges. Prove that $m(E)=0$ ($m$ is the Lebesgue measure in Rudin's notation).

I do not really know where to begin. I don't even understand Rudin's hint:

For every $A\subset E$, $\int_A \sin n_k x \, dx \rightarrow 0$, and $2\int_A (\sin n_k x)^2 dx = \int_A (1 - \cos 2n_k x) \, dx \rightarrow m(A)$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to prove the hint or  how to use the hint or both?

Comment: the former, i guess

Comment: The hint follows from [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-LebesgueLemma.html).

Comment: i don't see how...the domain of integration is not the same. anyway, we did not learn riemann-lebesgue in this course

Comment: To see how  Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma applies, let $f=\chi_A$ in the linked page. Did you learn anything about Fourier series? For example, something like Parseval's identity?